# Facebook 'Like' counters not working as expected

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I understand this is the main facebook developer community; I wanted to as a question and see if anyone can help? 
I built a wordpress photo portfolio blog - http://shutterliving.com/movember-moustache/
I have the official facebook plugin installed and I have its own LIKE button running at the top and bottom of the page.

I also have the ‘TFG social share’ plugin installed:

wordpress.org/support/plugin/twitter-facebook-google-plusone-share

I am now wondering if I have managed to set it up correctly as I am encountering some unexpected behavior.

When I preview an unpublished post, the LIKE counter (for the official plugin) is at 0, however the ‘TFG social share’ plugin shows a 12 count? Why is there a discrepancy? How can the post get a like count if it has yet to be published? When I create a new post and save it as a draft, then preview it, both LIKE counts are at 0.

When I go to the debugger tool and input my URL I get errors that I don’t really understand, but a bit of googling told me they were not serious errors. Not sure though on how to fix them? Any idea?

Also when I click on my URL link in the Fetched URL and the Canonical URL, it takes me to a ‘Page not found’ page? Is this normal? Should it not take me through to my homepage?
Response Code   200
Fetched URL shutterliving.com

Canonical URL   shutterliving.com

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="shutterLIVING" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="shutterLIVING" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="Jamie A Cowan&#039;s PhotoBlog     and Portfolio" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="178646462271083" />
```

I also associated the INSIGHTS analytics to my web page, however the information it shows is not accurate, ie it says I have only 55 LIKES on my page, however I have much more Likes that that 
http://shutterliving.com/movember-moustache/

This leads me to believe I have set something up incorrectly.

Can anyone help with any issue

Jamie.